# I am after something like this scrolling Latest news box

Tags: jquery, css

I have looked around at some jquery bits and I can't find anything similar.

Obviously a lot of it is in CSS layout but does anyone know this code?

http://osc4.template-help.com/wt_32151/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

> jCarousel is a jQuery plugin for
>   controlling a list of items in
>   horizontal or vertical order. The
>   items, which can be static HTML
>   content or loaded with (or without)
>   AJAX, can be scrolled back and forth
>   (with or without animation).

Comment: Excellent thats just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) (if you can use jQuery, of course), you should be able to use it to do something like this.

**edit** : fix typo ;)

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the OP is looking at jQuery solutions. That aside, someone else already suggested jCarousel (and without the typo).

Comment: typo is fixed, i've submited my answer too quickly.